# Expected number of steps before 1-d biased random walk hits a number, given it's before another number

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk

We have a biased 1-dimensional random walk on the number line. Each timestep, with probability $p$ such that $0<p<1$, it increments by $1$, otherwise it decrements by $1$. Conditioning on the fact that the random walk hit $-a$ before hitting $b$, we want to know the expected number of steps till it hit $-a$ (when starting at $0$).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk, I know that the expected number of steps till an unbiased random walk (i.e. $p=\frac{1}{2}$) hits either $-a$ or $b$ is $ab$. But how to derive for hitting just one side, and for biased random walks?

Comment: The techniques employed in the proposed duplicate (see @Yannick's Comment) suffice to solve this problem, but the present Question might be posed by someone at a level of study who would benefit from an exposition of that.  I'm voting to leave open in the hopes Yannick or someone else will find time to do that write-up (apologies for not tackling it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use stuff like discrete Laplacian?

Let $f(x)$ be the expectation of $\tau_{-a}$ conditioned on the event $\tau_{-a}<\tau_b$ with the biased walk starting from $x$, then we have $f(-a)=f(b)=0$ and for all $-a<i<b$, $p(1+f(i+1)-f(i))+(1-p)(1+f(i)-f(i-1))=0$.
Calculate the product of the left and right hand side, we get $1+f(i+1)-f(i)=(-\frac{1-p}{p})^(i+a) \dot (1+f(-a+1))$.
Then sum over I and use $f(b)=0$ to get the value of $f(-a+1)$.

I didn't calculate the rest of this method. Maybe it will work ;P

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!
Forgetting ’$’ is such a dumb mistake 